# How to overload operator + for const char* and int

Tags: c++, c++11, vb6-migration

I know this is silly and ugly, but I'm migrating some code automatically. My source language allows implicit conversion between strings and ints, and for example this is allowed:

```
var = "hello " + 2
print(var) # prints "hello 2"
```

How can I in C++ overload the + operator for `const char*` and `int`? I'm getting the error:

> error: ‘std::string operator+(char* const&, int)’ must have an
>   argument of class or enumerated type

Comment: You can't overload operators for built-in types.

Comment: There's already a built-in `+` operator for pointer+integer and integer+pointer. `"hello" + 2` yields a pointer to the first `'l'` character in the string. Since array indexing is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic, allowing you to hide the predefined operators would be really bad.

Comment: Nothing particularly wrong with `"hello " + std::to_string(2)`.

Comment: @chris Yes there is: I need to extend my type inference rules which are really basic and hard coded at the moment.

Comment: Are you migrating from VB6 to C++ and trying to keep that code? Not a good idea.

Comment: @user2672165 We have lots of VB6 code, do yoou have any better idea?

Comment: @vz0: If you want to accomplish a task, sometimes work is involved.  Sorry, but there's no easy shortcut here :/  You could add `something{} + "hello " + 2` that would do what you want, would that be acceptable?

Comment: @MooingDuck You gave me a nice idea! It is very easy to convert an string "Hello" to an std::string("Hello"). Thank you!

Comment: @vz0 do not, do not, I repeat do not overload `operator+(std::string, int)`.  Only overload operators on types you own, and you don't own types in `std`.  If you must have a `string` type that supports `+ int`, create your own that has a `std::string` field.

Comment: @Yakk This is a migration. While I agree the code should be beautiful, I also need the zillion lines of code to work. I am not overloading +(std::string, int) because the compiler does not like that :D

Comment: @Yakk i've just tried implementing my own mystr type. I don't like it, therefore i guess I'd have to fix the coercions by hand. Thanks!

Comment: @vz0 less about beauty, more about future proofing, maintainability, and breaking everyone elses' code by modifying the behavior of `std` types.  `struct mystr { std::string data; }` in C++11 is a reasonably functional aggregate string to start, and most `string` methods work with a simple `.str.whatever`, and overloading `+` on **that** is perfectly ok.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### What you are asking for is illegal

To legally overload an operator at least one of the operands involved has to be a *user-defined type*. Since neither `char*` nor `int` is *user-defined*, what you are trying to accomplish isn't possible.

This, what you are trying to do, is intentionally, and explicitly, disallowed in the standard. Don't you think it would be weird if suddenly `1+3 = 42` because someone "clever" have defined an overload for `operator+(int, int)`?

---

#### What does the Standard say? ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf))

> `13.3.1.2p1-2` **Operators in expressions** `[over.match.oper]`
>
> > If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a class or an enumeration, the operator is assumed to be a built-in operator and interpreted according to Clause 5.
> >
> > If either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration, a user-defined operator function might be declared that implements this operator or a user-defined conversion can be neccessary to convert the operand to a type that is appropriate for a built-in operator.

( **Note**: The wording is the same in both *C++03*, and the next revision of the standard; *C++14* )

Comment: Is it against the norm to overload `operator+` for `std::string` and `int`? That would provide a work around for the OP's needs.

Comment: @RSahu, I'm pretty sure it's technically illegal, but I can see that being something the C++ community is not fond of anyway.

Comment: @RSahu see Keith Thompson's comment on the question

Comment: @Brian It makes sense now.